# In R, is there an efficient way to compute/plot averages based on multiple explanatory variables?

Tags: r, plot

Here is what I am after:

Let's use the `ToothGrowth` dataset that comes with R as a simple example. In this dataset there are 3 columns: length, supplement, dose. Both dose and supplement are explanatory variables for length. It's easy enough to, say, plot dose against length and use the supplement as a factor. For instance, using qplot you would just do this:

```
qplot(x = ToothGrowth$dose , y = ToothGrowth$len, color = ToothGrowth$supp)
```

The next thing I'd want to do is see the trend of the average growth for each supplement as dose increased. I.e., construct a very similar plot, except I want the y variable to be the average of the values based on the dose and supplement.

I'm not sure how to do that in place with a call to qplot. It occurred to me that perhaps the thing to do was to compute a new column or something, but I'm also not sure how to use something like `mutate` to build a new column based on multiple explanatory variables.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be what you are looking for but you may need to clarify.  Here is how you can generate the averages using `dplyr`

```
Avg_ToothGrowth <- ToothGrowth %>%
  group_by(supp, dose) %>%
  summarise(avg_len = mean(len)) %>%
  ungroup

qplot(dose, avg_len, data = Avg_ToothGrowth, color = supp)
```

This should get you close but you may have to go through a `dplyr` tutorial to better understand the use of `group_by` and `summarise`.  I used the `ungroup` to strip off the remaining groupings as they are not needed (there may be a better way to do this).

**EDIT:**

You can also plot the original data with a trend line for each group

```
# With confidence interval
qplot(dose, len, data = ToothGrowth, color = supp, geom = c('smooth', 'point'), method = 'lm')
# Without confidence interval
qplot(dose, len, data = ToothGrowth, color = supp, geom = c('smooth', 'point'), method = 'lm', se=FALSE)
```

Comment: `tbl_df` is actually not needed.

Comment: For clarity, I removed the "tbl_df".

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to use `dplyr` as steveb did, but in case you are not familiar with the package, a solution without it might be easier to understand. The function `aggregate()` can help you:

```
tg <- aggregate(len ~ dose + supp, mean, data = ToothGrowth)
```

The first argument is a formula that tells the function that it should aggregate the value of the column `len` for all rows that have the same values for `dose` and `supp`. The second argument gives the function to use for the aggregation, which is `mean`. So, what is actually done is the following:

- Rows of the data frame are grouped together by `dose` and `supp`. All rows within a group have thus the same values for `dose` and `supp`.
- Then, for each group, the function `mean()` is applied to the column `len`.

This is exactly what is happening in the `dplyr` solution, but there, the two steps are more clearly spelled out.

The resulting data frame can then be plotted:

```
qplot(dose, len, colour = supp, data = tg)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer. I dig dplyr, but I'm still getting used to it. I was having trouble unpacking the dplyr explanation, but this one both helps clarify that answer as well as gives me a way to understand the process without any special package magic. Thanks!